# Convert date to datetime and set the time

Tags: sql-server

So I'm doing

> SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, t.MyDate)

And naturally it will convert something like 2014-01-01 to 2014-01-01 00:00:00.000

How do I convert and then set the time to whatever I want? For example, 23.59.59.999?

Comment: What is `MyDate`? And you can change the date and time using `dateadd()`.

Comment: Darn, I should have thought of that. Thanks. MyDate is just the column I'm working with. If you want to submit this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Please note that the DateTime data type is not precise to 1/1000 of a second, even though it appears that way.  Your example DateTime of `2014-01-01 23:59:59.999` will get rounded to `2014-01-02 00:00:00.000`.  See the rounding section, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add time to the date part:

```
select DateAndTime = convert(DateTime, '2015-03-17') + convert(Time, '23:59:59.999')
```

As a side note your time string was incorrect. The dot (`.`) divides only seconds and milliseconds. Use colon (`:`) for hours minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Okay.  If t.MyDate is a column, we need to insert the date along with the time information.  Converting this with the time information will help.

```
 select GETDATE()
--2015-03-17 23:35:20.220

select convert(datetime,'2015-03-17  23:35:20.220')
```

[Or]

```
select convert(DateTime, t.MyDate) + convert(Time, '23:59:59.999')
```